# Combine PhoneGap and Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cordova

Hello dear fellow Stackoverflowers,

I am new to mobile programming and I encountered a problem while researching PhoneGap.

I would like to use some Java EE functionalities like JDBC on the server, while the app should use the framework PhoneGap. For example, the PhoneGap app should have access to data stored in a database connected to a Java EE server.However, all articles and books I found so far gave me the impression that it is only possible to call these functions from a Java context. (Which would have to be J2ME here, I guess)

Is it possible to have some kind of interface on the server running Java EE that allows a PhoneGap application to make calls to it?

I am grateful for any answers :)

Comment: This is a bit general amigo. possible? sure pretty much all is .. but where's the code thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the art would be to write a JEE server applicaion and provide a webservice or REST API. Then you could read and write JSON or XML data with AJAX in your PhoneGap application.

Popular REST implementations are [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) or [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)

Comment: Great, I will look further into that. Thank you very much for your help, thobens!